# How to get paragraph data in textarea in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

how can I get paragraph content text in textarea value

```
<p ng-model="extrap" >Some parragraph content</p>
<textarea ng-model="oneps"></textarea>
```

```
<script>
(function() {
    angular
        .module("TextAngularDemo", ['textAngular'])
        .controller("DemoController", ['$scope', 'textAngularManager', DemoController]);

    function DemoController($scope, textAngularManager) {
        $scope.oneps = {{extrap}}
    };
})();
</script>
```

I want paragraph text in textarea box with prefilled paragraph text

Comment: Have you tried data-binding or just `placeholder`? If you want to display a value inside `textarea`, I think you can use ` <textarea ng-model="text" ng-init="text = 'Default text value'"></textarea>`

Comment: I want already written paragraph in textarea, by using this  <textarea ng-model="text" ng-init="text = 'Default text value'"></textarea> a fixed text is asigned to the textarea but parragraph content is changing.

Comment: <p> tag does not support ng-model attribute. <p> {{ yourScopevariable}} </p> and then put same in text area with same variable. So if that variable text gets changes, it would also reflect in text area

Comment: @SwabhavMishra Could you please clarify your requirement with an example?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to load a paragraph and text area with the same content, but you don't need to update the paragraph while the textarea value is changed. In that case you can go for one way data binding in `angular js`.

This can be achieved by adding `::` inside your interpolation symbol like `{{::yourModalValue}}`

See the example below to see the implementation.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myParagraphContent = "Some initial content.";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<b>Change the text area fild and see the change in me</b>
<p>{{myParagraphContent}}</p>

<b>Change the text area fild and see I won't be changes</b>
<p>{{::myParagraphContent}}</p>

<textarea ng-model="myParagraphContent"></textarea>

</div>
```

Comment: how to get any text between this line: some {{other text}} initial content

Comment: @SwabhavMishra Could you please clarify your requirement with an example?